# Is there a way to set inheritance in the same module with __PACKAGE__->?

Tags: perl, class, inheritance, constructor, dbi

For example I want to store the data for a dbi connection on startup so I do not have to initialize it through an object, is their a way to do this in the same package?

Initializing through my object would be:

```
my $obj = foo->new;
my $dbh = $obj->connect('dbi', 'user', 'pw');
```

But I want to store it at startup to where I can just use

```
my $obj = foo->new;
my $blah = $obj->selectall_arrayref(...);


package foo; 

use strict; 
use warnings;  

__PACKAGE__->connect('dbi', 'user', 'pw');    

sub new {   
 my $class = shift;   
 my $self  = {};   
 bless ($self, $class);   
 return $self; 
}   

 sub connect {   
  my $class = shift;   
  my $self  = ref $class || $class;   
  return $self->(@_);     # Is this possible? 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using a proxy object is to simply compose DBI into your class.

```
package foo;    
use DBI;

sub new {   
    my $class = shift;
    my $self  = {DBH => DBI->connect(@_)};   
    bless ($self, $class);   
    return $self; 
}

# defer method call to DBH
sub selectall_arrayref {shift->{DBH}->selectall_arrayref(@_)}

package main;    
my $obj = foo->new('dbi:...', 'user', 'password');
my $blah = $obj->selectall_arrayref(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing DBI class is not quite simple, just [read the documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#Subclassing-the-DBI).
Other way may be declare a [proxy object](https://metacpan.org/module/Class%3a%3aProxy), and call the wrapped object with the help of [AUTOLOAD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading).